# Using QUERY and IMPORTRANGE to pull records from a specific date range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have created two spreadsheets.

This one is my source data: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet_A](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ATkORZt0_vEUdyKMk1trWymhfJ5-aJPlMdRT0-yM9Q/edit#gid=0)**

And I would like this one to just be the people who are currently here (so Column D < today and Column E > today): **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets_B](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C5dk1lQF1C8NAAB5URrNSLg3KThtV-Wt6UtrRIR_I9o/edit#gid=0)**

I keep tinkering with the formula for the date, but can't get it right. Most recent error I've gotten is

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: A.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome. What is the formula that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

use `Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4` instead of `A,B,C,D` when you `QUERY` the `IMPORTRANGE`

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("16ATkORZt0_vEUdyKMk1trWymhfJ5-aJPlMdRT0-yM9Q", "A1:E"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col4 >= '"&TEXT(DATE(2018,1,2),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'", 1)
```

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("16ATkORZt0_vEUdyKMk1trWymhfJ5-aJPlMdRT0-yM9Q", "A2:D"),
 "select Col4 where Col4 >= '"&TEXT(DATE(2019,1,2),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'")
```

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("16ATkORZt0_vEUdyKMk1trWymhfJ5-aJPlMdRT0-yM9Q", "A1:E"), 
"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 where Col5 <= '" &TEXT(E2, "yyyy-MM-dd")& 
                                    "' AND Col4 >= '" &TEXT(D2, "yyyy-MM-dd")& "'")
```

## **UPDATE - final solution:**

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("16ATkORZt0_vEUdyKMk1trWymhfJ5-aJPlMdRT0-yM9Q", "A1:E"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col5 >= '"&TEXT(DATE(2019,1,2),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'
                               and Col4 <  '"&TEXT(DATE(2019,1,2),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for replying!

That first formula keeps giving me the date 2018-01-10.

The second formula just gives me my header rows and if I edit the row number manually in subsequent rows, it imports everyone, not just our current folks. Thanks!

Comment: @user205206 yeah, try now 2nd one

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! We're getting closer; I've got my people, but it's still importing everyone.

Comment: There's a Jan 10 19 arrival and a Dec 28 18 departure in there, so those two shouldn't import.

Comment: @user205206 I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by @user0 with:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("16ATkORZt0_vEUdyKMk1trWymhfJ5-aJPlMdRT0-yM9Q", "A1:E"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col5 >= '"&TEXT(DATE(2019,1,2),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'
                               and Col4 <  '"&TEXT(DATE(2019,1,2),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'", 1)
```